# How to remove files from upload array (before upload) via Javascript

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multipartform-data, dom-manipulation

In simplest terms, I have a file select form which allows for multiple files to be selected for upload:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="image_upload_form">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="image_upload" name="files_to_upload[]" onchange="ini_image_upload();" />
</form>
```

Once files are selected, I run a quick Ajax call to check the database if certain files have already been uploaded, make sure there's no invalid files, etc. and create an array of files that already exist/I don't want to upload.

Now, I am trying to REMOVE these unwanted, scummy files from my upload array (before the actual upload IE. form gets submitted).

How do I achieve this majestically feat?

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion for you. It is better to use below for your
requirement for upload. Have a look onto below URL.It is really so easy to integrate into your existing system and lots of features available.

> http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I already know about this but I'm actually building a bespoke system for a client and this doens't fit the requirement.

Comment: I am just wondering , how you will build a system more powerful than uploadify.

Comment: Look man, im not trying to build something more powerful than uploadify, im not trying to compete with uploadify. Uploadify is king, OK! Are you happy now? I just wanted to enquire how to remove files from a particular array, is that too much to ask?

Comment: OK Alert.. try this 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/javascript-array-remove-element-js-array-delete-element.html
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: mate i really appreciate ur help but if it was just as simple as that i wouldn't be on stack overflow would i? what do u do for a living?

Answer (score 0):

what are you going to validate files by? are you trying to remove files with like some tricky extenstions like .php, .asp, .aspx ? if so then in the form element you should add a onSubmit attribute and call a function from there. then in the function check all the file names and process them and remove them from the array then replace the upload array and then return true. it would submit the form.. I actually don't know how u can retrieve the filenames form the upload array but Im pretty sure that this solution should work.

good luck!